# Turn on Flashlight while capture video on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Well, i'm a newbie developer in C# and i want to capture Video meanwhile the flashlight on device is turn on. I have been search for the answer, but they are lead me to make the flashlight app.

What i need is to capture video meanwhile the flashlight/torch is enabled. And , i think it possible , because when i open the camera app on my Lumia 710 (WP 7.8), i can recording while the flashlight was on.

Please help bro , if there are any references , course i will read it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Direct Show library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft: